# ASP.NET MVC Patterns for Multiple Tenants and Plugins?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, design-patterns, module

I am trying to understand how I can create an ASP.NET MVC site that exists as a VS2010 project in a solution, and then for multiple "tenants" I would create a site that inherits from that one. That would give the flexibility of adding modular features to one without affecting another one, and both could benefit from core library optimizations.

Is that a crazy idea? What patterns exist for that kind of thing? I have done something similar for a webform-based site (adding DLLS as plugins), but not in MVC.

A "tenant" is a business client. Each already has their own MSSQL database and seperate processing around them, each client is in its own silo. The databases are similar with a few features added here and there, they are versioned and deployed seperately, that whole process works well. A client has n logons. I want to develop a single "base site" that can then be used to give function to a tenant, and all activities are segerated for a tenant to a single database. Where things get ugly is how I can add a new component (say a forum) to one tenant site without mucking up the site experience for other tenants.

All ideas appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Explaining what you are trying to accomplish with the tenant projects would probably go a long way to guiding you (and us) toward a good answer. How do you envision a plugin interacting with the MVC structure of the site?

Comment: That's one of the reasons why DotNetNuke (a heavily plugin and modular based CMS) never took the decision to migrate to ASP.NET MVC. There simply are the right tools for the right job: http://www.dotnetnuke.com/Resources/Blogs/EntryId/2464/ASP-NET-MVC-and-DotNetNuke.aspx

Comment: Darin, I think that is where I am torn, because DNN has a monster of a deployment footprint, and 75% of what I need is CRUD using sprocs, not something DNN or any other CMS seems to do well.

Answer (score 0):

I have worked extensively on the development of a multi-tenant web application. Here are three basic pointers to help you get started:

**Security**

The TenantId is part of the login credentials. These are stored in the Thread.CurrentPrincipal. This effectively binds each request (thread) to a specific user and thus tenant. Thread.CurrentPrincipal can be easily accessed from any code.

**Database**

We used a single database to store all data. A separation was made between tables (entities) that were specific for one tenant (multi-tenant), and tables that were not (cross-tenant). Tables that were multi-tenant had a column called 'TenantId'. In our entity model, we made sure these entities inherited from a special IMultiTenant interface. This interface contained the C# equivalent of the TenantId field. We extended the  architecture of Entity Framework to provide default filtering on TenantId for multi-tenant entities. This ensured that one tenant could never access or modify the data of another tenant.

**Plugins**

We used a bit of Dependency Injection trickery in order to support the implementation of tenant specific code. Based on the current TenantId, our DI container injects a tenant-specific implementation of that interface.